# validations in MVC2/MVC3 with out DataAnnotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

can we validate a form which has few textboxes and i want to validate them for require field etc. by using javascriptfunctions in the samepage(.aspx/.cshtml).

i dont want to use DataAnnotations in Model.

Answer (score 1):

Only validating on the client is a bad idea, and insecure.  You need to *ALWAYS* do server side validation, and only do client-side validation as a "nice to have".  Otherwise validation can be bypassed by any attacker just by bypassing the client-side script.

There are several ways to do server (and client) side validation without data annotations.  You can use [Metadata "buddy" classes](http://hartzer.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/mvc-buddy-class/) and apply the attributes to the buddy class.  Or you can use [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/).  You can also use IValidatableObject.  You really really really should use some kind of server side validation though.

Answer (score 0):

In mvc 3, With Model DataAnnotations You can do javascript validations in client side. It uses jquery validate script to do the validations.

> in ASP.NET MVC 3 Beta, we’ve updated the runtime to enable a feature
>   we’re calling “Unobtrusive Client Validation”. We have also created a
>   consumer for these unobtrusive client validation attributes that uses
>   jQuery and jQuery Validate to perform the validation on our behalf.

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html

You should never rely on client side validation only. Do both client side and server side. What if somebody is accessing your website from a javascript disabled browser ?

Comment: @Santosh : I just tried it in google chrome and it worked fine.

Comment: hmmmm..how come its not working for me...anyways i want to use some thing like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497226/validating-form-in-mvc3-using-javascript

Comment: but the way he has done inthe above link is not working for me